# wordpress form submission not working with custom permalinks

Tags: wordpress, forms, permalinks

I created a form with post method and action=" " in index.php of theme(Home page).

```
<form name="filter" action="" method="post">
```

and I use custom permalink on **/%postname%/**
but during submit form, my data not posting to home page.
and when I changed Wordpress permalinks to "Plain" (numeric post id) my submission post works fine and my data posted to home page.